# Can someone please help me identify the first kanji in the image?

Tags: kanji

[image]

What is the first kanji? Is it 宵?

Answer (score 5):

The first kanji is 宵{よい}, yes. The character alone means evening (though sometimes also leans towards a meaning of "night" in Chinese)

> 宵{よい}の刻{こく}

means "evening" under this context.

Due to the constraints on size of characters and pixels, I suppose they could only write one line in the 月 part for it to still be readable. Obviously a trait of most video games of the time in Japanese (as is general awkwardness with reading some Kanji, though context does often give it away).

Answer (score 2):

I think it's 宵{よい}の刻{こく}, and means "evening time". More info [here](http://classic.jisho.org/kanji/details/%E5%AE%B5).